# Display an index next to a post — WP & Twig/Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I'm new to both WP and Twig/Timber. I'm working on a website where I need to display a number next to a WP post as such:

1. First post
2. Second post
3. Third post

…And so on

I couldn't find any information on how to do it. Can I achieve this with Twig/Timber? Also, I don't know much about it, but if it's recommended to use ACF for that, I would be open to it.

Thank you

**Edit**: I would like to display post number(s) both on a page which contains all the blog posts and on each post page.

**Edit 2**: I'm hoping there is a robust solution which would account for deleted posts

Comment: Why don't you just use an `ol` or a css counter?

Comment: So you have an overview page and then another page which display the number of the post? I'd guess u'd have to create an extra field for your posts first and store it in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that exists in Twig's loop variable that should make it super-easy:

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Comment: Thank you! But I've been using `loop.revindex` on the home page. Can I also use the loop on post pages? (I've tried but couldn't figure it out)

Comment: Ahhh, I see — you're looking to have that same value carry through to the post page itself? You'd have to somehow save that value to a custom field. In your `index.php` file you could store the value using `update_post_meta` in order to pass it to the post in the DB. This would be more of a standard PHP/WordPress type thing with Twig/Timber simply outputting the value of that new field. Otherwise the `loop` variable isn't present on the single page (since it's a single object and not a loop)

Comment: Will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Twig filter to query a custom post number index which is saved in a transient: the order is currently set to the menu order and transient is cached for 1 minute.

**Twig**

```
{{ post.id|get_post_number }}
```

**php**

```
/**
 * Adds functionality to Twig.
 * 
 * @param \Twig\Environment $twig The Twig environment.
 * @return \Twig\Environment
 */
add_filter( 'timber/twig', 'add_to_twig' );
function add_to_twig( $twig ) {

    // Adding functions as filters.
    $twig->addFilter( new Timber\Twig_Filter( 'get_post_number', 'get_post_number_by_id' ) );

    return $twig;
}

/**
 * Get post number from ID, based on menu order.
 *
 * @param [type] $id
 * @return void
 */
function get_post_number_by_id( $id ) {

    // Check we have a string
    $target_id =  strval( $id );

    // Save quesry and index in transient
    $post_number_index = Timber\Helper::transient(
        'get_post_number_by_id',
        function () {

            // Update parameters to match desired search order
            $args = array(
                'orderby'    => 'menu_order',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
            );

            // Query
            $posts = get_posts( $args );
            if ( !empty( $posts ) ) {
                
                // Store list
                $data = [];
                
                // Set post numer count
                $count = 0;

                // build index.
                foreach( $posts as $post ) {
                    $data[ $post->ID ] = array(
                        'post_id' => $post->ID,
                        'post_number' => ++$count,
                    );
                }

                return !empty( $data ) ? $data : false;
            }
            return false;
        },
        MINUTE_IN_SECONDS
    );

    // Retrun post number
    if ( !empty ( $post_number_index ) && array_key_exists( $target_id, $post_number_index ) ) {
        return $post_number_index[ $target_id ]['post_number'];
    }

    return false;

}
```